# Qpython import modules in script

Tags: python-requests, qpython

I have installed qpython for android, the problem is that when I install a module with pip in the python console I can import it properly, but not when I try to import it to a script.

in console ... I type:

```
>>>import requests
>>>requests
<module 'requests' from '/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/.../__init__.py>
```

but in a script saved in scripts' folder, when I execute:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I get this:

**import requests

ImportError: no module named requests**

Can anybody help with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add import site.

This works on my tablet:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:console
import site
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```